# How to block unusual bot, like "bot[\s_ :,\.\;\/\\-]" name?

Tags: .htaccess, bots

until today I was blocking unwanted bots in .htaccess

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*mj12bot.* bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*baiduspider.* bad_bot
```

But I noticed lastly that I have unusual bot making mess on my serwer but don't know how to block it because his name is:

```
bot[\s_ :,\.\;\/\\-]
```

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to deny requests for **bot[\s_ :,.\;/\-]**

```
SetEnvIfNoCase user-agent bot\[.+\]|mj12bot|baiduspider bad_bot=1
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

To block multiple user-agents, you may use :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase user-agent bot\[.+\]|.*mj12bot.*|.*baiduspider.* bad_bot=1
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly, "bot[\s_ :,\.\;\/\\-]" isn't blocked

Answer (score 0):

Through website statistics from my provider I found out that a hit by bot[\s_ :,.;/-] coincided with a visit by bingbot in my apache_access.log.
Blocking bingbot (it does not follow robots.txt) in .htaccess resulted in a few dozens of hits instead of thousands.

EDIT:

from https://github.com/eldy/AWStats/blob/develop/robots.pm

'bot[\s_+:,.;/\-]','Unknown robot (identified by 'bot*')',
'[\s_+:,.;/\-]bot','Unknown robot (identified by '*bot')',